# Demolishing a shed floor made of plywood. Can I use circular saw?

Tags: demolition, circular-saw

I just tore down my backyard shed. All that is left is the base/floor, which is plywood. Basically, I want it in small pieces so I can bag it for disposal.

I have a low power Li-ion reciprocating saw with a "green wood" super aggressive blade, which I know can do the job, but I also have a corded 15-amp 7 1/2 circular saw lying around. It is much more powerful, and I know it rips plywood much much quicker and effortlessly.

My general safety understanding of the circular saw is, one side of what you're cutting should not be fastened (free to fall off), or else it may kick back. So, would it be unsafe to run a circular saw through a plywood floor fastened to a wooden frame on the ground?

Answer (score 1):

A circular saw can be used to plunge cut into flooring cut out sections for repair/access.  I don't see how this would be any different.  Just make sure you adjust the blade depth for the width of the plywood.so that you don't hit anything that might be under the shed (support beams/metal/concrete/small animals too stupid to move/etc).

Comment: Agree, though hand, ear and especially eye protection are important here. Expect to hit a nail or screw, so use an old/disposable blade. Do keep 2 hands on the saw. If you don't have a good level of comfort plunge cutting with the saw, do a bit of research -- it's not hard, but done wrong it can be bad.